Liferay upgrade ClassNotFound "import com.liferay.portal.kernel.security.auth.session.AuthenticatedSessionManagerUtil;"
I am upgrading my application from Liferay 7.2 to 7.4 ga112.
We are using AuthenticatedSessionManagerUtil.login() for user login. I have found that :

com.liferay.portal.kernel.security.auth.session.AuthenticatedSessionManagerUtil;

the session packages are removed. Can someone help if this Class is moved to other package?

Just search for a class with the same name in the current source tree: com.liferay.portal.security.auth.session.AuthenticatedSessionManagerUtil.java
And then look at the "git blame" output. It's quite easy to identify the commit with its comment that this class was moved with:

breaking_change_report
What portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/security/auth/session/AuthenticatedSessionManagerUtil.java
AuthenticatedSessionManagerUtil is being moved to portal-impl
Why
We are merging portal-kernel into portal-impl as a long term goal to simplify portal structure.
Alternatives
Add portal-impl in build dependency and use the same class.

